# jquery how to call function from external .js file

Tags: jquery, function, call, external

I'm trying to figure out the jQuery code syntax for calling a function in a separate .js file still referenced with a script href tag in my head tags.  So here is essentially what I have.

```
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Publish/Depts/EWI/scripts/prehomefunctions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Publish/Depts/EWI/scripts/feedFunctions.js"></script>
  </head>

  //Inside feedFunctions.js
  if(condition){functionName1()};

  //Inside prehomefunctions.js
  function functionName1(){
    ///DO SOMETHING
  };
```

at this point whenever I try to execute this my feedFunctions.js file throws an error saying that "functionName1" is not a function because the file cannot find this function within itself, but I'm trying to make it point to prehomefunctions.js to find this function.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have a feeling it has something to do with the fact that I'm calling and defining the function (in the separate js files) within my $(document).ready(function(){ ; but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. The js file is not found Or there is a JS error preventing functionName1 from being defined. If you do not have a JS debugging tool, try adding alerts. start right before the function name:

```
alert ('made it!')
```

function functionName1(){ 
    ///DO SOMETHING 
  };

If it does not alert you, you have a syntax error further up your script.

Break this down to the simplist implementation and add the real-work complexity. your error wil be come evident.

Comment: I have done this already, I get the alert back but get an error saying "functionName1 is not defined"

Comment: There is proablly a syntax error in the function body. Can you post the code for Function1?

Comment: +1 I'm new to JavaScript This helped me thx bro "If it does not alert you, you have a syntax error further up your script."

Answer (score 3):

Browser JavaScript is not "inside files" : the contents of the files are executed *as part of the document itself* when the including `<script>` tags are encountered. So, if `prehomefunctions.js` defines function `functionName1` and is included before `feedFunctions.js` which calls `functionName1`, everything should work.

There's probably something else that you have not explained which is causing your code to break.